# Browserify a library rather than a file

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I am tryng to use npm libraries in browsers. Taking the npm library [uniq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniq) as an example, at the moment, we need first to write locally the code that uses `uniq`:

```
// main.js
var unique = require('uniq');    
var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];
console.log(unique(data));
```

Then, we need to run `browserify` in a console:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Now, we could use it in a html file:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

My question is, **whether it is possible to browserify a library such that any code inside the "script" tag could use it.** For example, in the html part, I may want to write

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="the_browserified_library.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
       <!-- the following code may change -->
       var d = [1, 1, 2, 3];
       console.log(unique(d));
       var a = [2, 2, 4, 5];
       console.log(unique(a));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If it is possible, we will not have to browserify (in a console) the code each time after changing it.

Does anyone know if it is possible by browserify or any other tools?

**Edit 1**: following the answer of @dNitro, I installed `globalify` globally, but later it gives an error:

```
/tmp/client$ globalify uniq -o uniq.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/globalify/node_modules/camelcase/index.js:4
    let isLastCharLower = false;
    ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/globalify/globalify.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want make **global** variable of a npm package?! Use [globalify](https://github.com/KoryNunn/globalify):

#### installation:

```
npm install globalify -g
```

#### Usage:

```
globalify uniq -o uniq.js
```

then in your html:

```
<script src="uniq.js"></script>    
<script>
  var d = [1, 1, 2, 3];
  console.log(uniq(d));
</script>
```

**Note** that you should avoid polluting global scope. writing code this way is harmful. browserify not only make your code browser ready, it helps you write clean (doesn't pollute global window scope), modular (the CommonJS or ES6 way) and future proof (write ES6 and transpile it on bundle time) and your app is ready with just one http request to *bundle.js* file.

If running browserify everytime you change your code, bothers you, you could consider using **[watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify)**; It automatically rebuild the bundle on every change you made in your files.

Comment: Thank you... please see my update. Also, we still need to use `globalify` in a console in the beginning. Is there a way to automatically turn any (or most of) npm node.js library browser-compatible? I don't see how to automate this `globalify` command (which relies on a console) in the server or in a browser...

Comment: @SoftTimur, Seems your node does not support ES2015 syntax, check your node version: `node -v`. If your node version is less than `v5.0.0` you should upgrade. `globalify` besides *cmdline* also has an **API**. you could require it and run `globalify()` to do its job. just make an array of your desired packages loop over them and give it one by one to `globalify()` then write them to disk. See: [API example](https://github.com/KoryNunn/globalify)